# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes after login with amdgpu problems

Tags: 20.04, amdgpu

To try and figure out what was going on I went into virtual terminal 3 and dug this error up. (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/230758481240653834/798990921152724992/Screenshot_20210113-140322_Discord.jpg)
The laptop is an Alpha 15 A3DD from Msi.